# Права доступа и ошибки в WordPress на Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

Прошу помочь. Недавно начал изучать WordPress по этому плейлисту: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URFhyvZTENc
Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что постоянно приходится вводить пароль от имени администратора ради любого действия. Будь то сохранение или изменение файла. Отнимает слишком много времени. Я не понимаю в чём дело. Поставил на все необходимые файлы максимальные права доступа через chmod и это не помогает. Запуск каталога от имени администратора тоже ни к чему не приводит. Ещё недавно воспользовался командой chown для этих каталогов и файлов. Было бы неплохо, если вы объясните почему у меня в системе фактически есть два пользователя: root и acer. Я acer, но можно сказать, что все самые главные файла отведены под root. Если что-то непонятно - спрашивайте. Навряд ли я смог описать всё, что нужно.
[image: ][1]]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пароль какого "администратора"? Причём тут ВП, если говоришь о файлах?

Comment: Если не хотите мучиться с правами в /opt, установите lamp в домашнюю директорию.

Answer (score 1):

Доброе утро. Тут WP непричем, у вас проблемма с правами на файлы. Вот очень хорошая сылка на эту [тему про права](https://losst.ru/prava-dostupa-k-fajlam-v-linux). Если посмотреть на права на файлы которые вы выставили, то видно, что права у вас выставленны не коректно. Наверное правильно будет выставить права на имя web-сервера, `sudo chown -R name_deamon:name_deamon /opt/lampp/htdocs/wordpress/*` после этого вы сможете редактировать файлы из панели `wordpress` так же можете добавить себя в групу web-сервера и выставить права по ссылке выше, и сможете редактировать файлы из консоли.